# ASP.net giving me blank value

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
String name, gender, DOB, email, mob, land, address, state, city, pincode;
    name = txtname.Text.Trim();
   gender = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
   DOB = txtDob.Text.Trim();
    email = txtemail.Text.Trim();
    mob = txtmob.Text.Trim();
   land = txtlandline.Text.Trim();
   address = txtaddress.Text.Trim();
   state = txtstate.Text.Trim();
   city = txtcity.Text.Trim();
   pincode = txtpincode.Text.Trim();
   Response.Write("<script>alert('"+email+"')</script>");
```

This code on click giving me black value why ??

I tried a lot but I didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like the following sample and it works. Let me know if you have any other issue.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />

</p>
```

The codebehind for the button click is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name, gender, DOB, email, mob, land, address, state, city, pincode;
        email = txtemail.Text.Trim();
        Response.Write("<script> alert('" + email + "')</script>");
    }
```

Also, debug your code and find if you get value for the txtemail control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to popup your alert email ID , you can try following code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String name, gender, DOB, email, mob, land, address, state, city, pincode;
    email = txtemail.Text.Trim();
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('"+ email "');", true);
}
```

try it...